# What is the purpose of an android phone continuously accessing the internet every ≈10 seconds?

Tags: wi-fi, internet

Why would a stationary phone on Wi-Fi need to access the internet every few seconds as shown by the arrows near the Wi-Fi icon top right corner of the home screen?

Does this happen also off Wi-Fi but with no arrows indicator?

Data Saver is on and operate in background button is off for all apps.

Comment: You can find it out yourself: Install an app like [PCAPDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.emanuelef.remote_capture), capture traffic for a few minutes and then load the generated pcap file into Wireshark.

Comment: For the same purpose any other computer does the exact same?

Comment: @ChanganAuto a user might not know why a computer would do the same too. You would want to expand on that.

Comment: Many devices automatically access the internet for updates, refresh data, and ping in on their location.  There are ways to stop the access like Data Saver, Manual Updates, and Do Not Run In Background for a cell phone but those do not stop an S22 from upload/down load of data about every 10 seconds.  I would like to know the purpose of the continuous data traffic when on Wi-Fi.